# How to utilize the Unit of Work pattern with repositories in onion architecture that query external APIs?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, onion-architecture

There are many excellent resources about the Unit of Work pattern. My understanding is that it's main purpose is to provide a way to ensure that the effects of a piece of code will not persist if an error occurs. There are plenty of examples of this usage for databases in most languages.

There are very few resources I can find about using such patterns to query and use external APIs while maintaining some level of data integrity during an error. Generally repositories are about data persistence but a lot of API's do concern such things especially in a microservice architecture. [Clean Architecture: Where to make API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66293364/clean-architecture-where-to-make-api-calls) suggests that such a microservice architecture should abstract calls to other microservices using a repository, and there are many public APIs that can be thought of in a similar manner.

In my specific case, I am looking to plug in the Todoist API for `Task` items into my application which works with its own version of a `Todo` entity. I have successfully adapted my `TodoRepository` for the Todoist API and can see my tasks from Todoist displayed in my UI - I now face the issue that if a call fails then I could be adding, deleting or updating a Task in the Todoist API when an error occurs after the call, which is not ideal for data integrity reasons.

There seems to be some distinction between an API that can act as a repository and one that cannot. Seemingly, if the API is able to perform general CRUD on a similar entity in the modelled entity then it may be a good candidate for a repository adapter, but if it were something like retrieving the weather forecast, determining if a name is the same as some celebrity, working with the google maps API (if your application wasn't a map itself), etc, then these are handled differently.

Under the assumption that I have not yet confirmed that all API adapters/facades will be implemented in the Infrastructure layer of a project, what context does the interface that defines the API usage exist? If I want to query to see if a name is also a celebrity name, would I have an Application or Domain service interface that looks something like

```cs
public interface CelebrityService {
    Celebrity LinkNameToCelebrity(string first_name, string last_name);
}
```

Where Celebrity is a Domain entity. This feels out of place if the Celebrity entity has been made only for this call.

Similarly for a weather API,

```cs
public interface WeatherService {
    Weather GetWeatherForDay(datetime day);
}
```